# What the difference between loadComplete and gridComplete events?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, jqgrid

This question originated after I looked on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4943722/1818608) answer of [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) and demo-grids in it.

`gridComplete`:

> This fires after all the data is loaded into the grid and all other
>   processes are complete. Also the event fires independent from the
>   datatype parameter and after sorting paging and etc.

`loadComplete`:

> This event is executed immediately after every server request.  data
>   Data from the response depending on datatype grid parameter

From that docs I understood that `gridComplete` fires at the end of drawing grid, and `loadComplete` fires after jqGrid completes communication with backend.

And so I wonder - why in demos, `loadComplete` used for change color of cells and not `gridComplete`?

Comment: without a ton of familiarity with the differences between the loadComplete and gridComplete properties, i would assume that loadComplete loads all data, styling, layout, and spacing, while gridComplete just takes the data from the loadComplete method and render's the grid in the view.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think that this question is asked by many users of jqGrid. So it's interesting to know the answer.

I personally prefer to use `loadComplete`. If you examine code from all my examples which I posted, you will find `gridComplete` only when the Original Poster posted it in the question and I would have modified a little code. I prefer to use `loadComplete` because of some advantages of `loadComplete` and disadvantages of `gridComplete`.

Here are advantages of `loadComplete`:

- It's the last callback which will be called if *the whole grid body* will be reloaded. For example after loading the page on the grid from the server. It's important to understand, that if the user changes sorting of some column or sets filter or chooses another page of the grid; the grid body will be reloaded.
- `loadComplete` has parameter `data` which represent full page of local data or full data loaded from the server.

On the other side `gridComplete` will be called (in the current version of jqGrid 4.4.4) from internal `updatepager` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L1736)), which **will be called from `delRowData` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L2861)), `addRowData` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L3057)) and `clearGridData` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L3468)) methods; in addition** to `addXmlData` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L1289)) and `addJSONData` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L1471)). It's not what one mostly want.

Another disadvantage of `gridComplete` one can see if one examines the code of `addXmlData` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L1289)) and `addJSONData` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L1471)) *from where* `updatepager` is called and so `gridComplete` will be called. If one uses `loadonce: true` and the internal parameters `data` and `_index` will be filled with full data returned from the server. One can see when using `loadonce: true`; the callback **`gridComplete` will be called after the first page of data are loaded from the sever**. At this moment `data` and `_index` contains only the data for the page. On the other side **`loadComplete` will be called later after all data returned from the server are processed and saved locally** in `data` and `_index`.

If you load the data from the server and if you don't use `loadonce: true` option, `clearGridData`, `addRowData` and `delRowData` then you could use `gridComplete` instead of `loadComplete`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source of jqGrid [(source)](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js) you can see that gridComplete is called on just one line of grid.base.

`1725: if($.isFunction(ts.p.gridComplete)) {ts.p.gridComplete.call(ts);}`

This line comes from the function `updatePager`.

You can find `loadComplete` in the `populate` function (line 1757). Unlike `gridComplete`, it is passed an extra parameter. Both callbacks receive a reference to `this`, but `loadComplete` also receives the data returned from the server (or passed in locally):

```
1858: case "xmlstring": 
if(lcf) {ts.p.loadComplete.call(ts,dstr);}

1869: case "jsonstring": 
if(lcf) {ts.p.loadComplete.call(ts,dstr);}

1881: 
case "local":
case "clientside":
if(lc) { lc.call(ts,req); }
```

The thing is, the functions `populate` and `updatePager` often happen in tandem, so you see that when sorting and paging, both callbacks are called. The difference, once again, is that `loadComplete` is passed an extra parameter.

There are probably subtle differences that I haven't encountered yet... and there might be cases where one is called and the other isn't, but I have noticed that on sorting and paging, both are called.