# jqGrid how to collapse row when clicking on other row

Tags: jqgrid, row, edit, selected

In a main grid, when I click on one row, it become 'highlighted' and the seven subgrids are showed.
Here is an example where first row is selected, and near to be edited (work in progress) :
[image]

Now, if I click on second row of the main grid, the first is hidden and the second selected. I click after on edit button and a warning appears : no selected row !

[image]

If I click again on the second row, it become unselected, and again I click for selecting and editing, that runs fine ! So I presume that my code for switching between collapsed and expanded status is somewhere wrong :

**UPDATED 2013-04-11**

Following Oleg's answer, I join the full code (limited to 30000) of my program :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var resetAltRows = function () {
    $(this).children("tbody:first").children('tr.jqgrow').removeClass('myAltRowClass');
    $(this).children("tbody:first").children('tr.jqgrow').each(function(){
        var arbo=$(this).find('td:eq(0)').text().substr(0,1);
        $(this).addClass('myAltRowClass1'+arbo);
        if(arbo==1)$(this).find('td:eq(1) input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    });
    $(this).children("tbody:first").children('tr.jqgrow:visible:odd').addClass('myAltRowClass');
};

var OldSelectedRow=null,
        height=$('body').height()-235,
        numRows=Math.floor(height/23)-(Math.floor(height/23)%5),
        heightRows=numRows*23,
        myGrid = $("#tab51");

//************************
//************************
//************************
myGrid.jqGrid({
    caption:"Liste des BONS DE TRAVAUX STANDARD",
    hidegrid:false,
    url:'opt511.php',
    datatype: "json",
    height:heightRows,
    rowNum:numRows,
    shrinkToFit:true,
    colNames:['Id','A.R.C.','B.T.','Date ARC','Client','Nom','Ville','Cde client','Matériel','Marque','Prest.','Description','N° série','Objet','X','b.type','idref'],
    colModel:[  
        {name:'b.id',index:'b.id', hidden:true,key:true}, 
        {name:'b.arc',index:'b.arc', width:60,align:'center',editable:true}, 
        {name:'b.ind',index:'b.ind', width:30,align:"center"},
        {name:'b.date_in',index:'b.date_in', width:70,align:"center"}, 
        {name:'c.code',index:'c.code', width:40}, 
        {name:'c.descr',index:'c.descr',width:200},
        {name:'c.ville',index:'c.ville', width:200}, 
        {name:'b.cde_clt',index:'b.cde_clt', width:150}, 
        {name:'q.code',index:'q.code', width:80}, 
        {name:'k.code',index:'k.code', width:80}, 
        {name:'b.nature',index:'b.nature', stype:'select',width:40,align:'center',
            searchoptions:{
                dataUrl:'sh51.php'
            },
            cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                return 'title="' + rawObject[15] + '"';
            }
        }, 
        {name:'2m.descr',index:'2m.descr', width:200}, 
        {name:'p.numserie',index:'p.numserie', width:80}, 
        {name:'b.descr',index:'b.descr', width:200}, 
        {name:'clos',index:'clos', width:20,stype:'select',align:'center',sortable:false,
            searchrules:{date:true}, 
            search:true,
            searchoptions:{
                value:{"": "?", 0:"En cours", 1: "Clôturé"},
                defaultValue:0
            }
        }, 
        {name:'btype',index:'btype', width:40,hidden:true},
        {name:'idref',index:'btype', width:40,hidden:true}
    ], 
    postData: {
            filters:'{"groupOp":"AND","rules":['+
                            '{"field":"clos","op":"eq","data":"0"}]}'
    },
    search:true,
    pager: '#tab51p', 
    sortname: 'b.arc', 
    gridComplete:function(){
        OldSelectedRow=null;
        sortDataCol(this);,
    },
    onSelectRow:function(id,status){
        alert('begin = '+myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'));
        if(OldSelectedRow!=id){
            if(OldSelectedRow!=null){
                myGrid.jqGrid ('collapseSubGridRow', OldSelectedRow);
                $('#'+OldSelectedRow).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
            }
            $('#'+id).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
            OldSelectedRow=id;
            myGrid.jqGrid('expandSubGridRow',id);
        }else{
            myGrid.jqGrid ('collapseSubGridRow', id);
            $('#'+id).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
            OldSelectedRow=null;
        }
        alert('end = '+myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'));
    },
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        //*********************
        //  1ST SUBGRID
        //*********************
        var rowdata = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',row_id),
            btr=rowdata['b.id'],
            subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_a", 
            pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id; 
        $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>"); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({ 
            url:"sg511a.php?id="+row_id+"&btr="+btr, 
            datatype: "json", 
            colNames: ['Nature','Information'],
            colModel: [ 
                {name:'c.code',index:'c.code', width:150,align:'right',sortable:false}, 
                {name:'p.coeff',index:'p.coeff', width:630,sortable:false}
            ], 
            height: '100%',
            autowidth:true,
            caption:'1 - INFORMATIONS CLIENT',
        }); 
        //*********************
        //  2ND SUBGRID 
        //*********************
        var clt=rowdata['c.code'],
            subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_b", 
            pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id; 
        $("#"+subgrid_id).append("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>"); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({ 
            url:"sg511b.php?id="+row_id+"&clt="+clt, 
            datatype: "json", 
            colNames: ['Id','X','Civilité','Nom','Prénom','Service'],
            colModel: [ 
                {name:'t.id',index:'t.id', width:60, align:"center",hidden:true}, 
                {name:'check',index:'check', width:20,sortable:false,formatter:'checkbox',align:'center',
                    editable: false, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: {value: "true:false", defaultValue: "false"}, 
                    formatoptions: {disabled: false}
                },
                {name:'v.code',index:'v.code', width:60,sortable:false},  
                {name:'t.nom',index:'t.nom', width:210,sortable:false}, 
                {name:'t.prenom',index:'t.prenom', width:210,sortable:false},
                {name:'f.descr',index:'f.descr', width:220,sortable:false}
            ], 
            pager: pager_id, 
            sortname: 't.nom',
            hiddengrid:true,
            scroll:true,
            maxheight: 230,
            autowidth:true,
            caption:'2 - PERSONNES A CONTACTER',
            gridComplete:function(){
                OldSelectedRow=null;
                sortDataCol(this);
                    }
        }); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{search:false,add:false,edit:false,del:false});
        //*********************
        //  3TH SUBGRID 
        //*********************
        rowdata = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',row_id);
        var parc=rowdata['p.id'];
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id; 
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_c"; 
        pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id; 
        $("#"+subgrid_id).append("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>"); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({ 
            url:"sg511c.php?id="+row_id+"&parc="+parc, 
            datatype: "json", 
            colNames: ['Id','Ensemble','Quantité','Article','Désignation','Matière'],
            colModel: [ 
                {name:'a.id',index:'a.id', width:60, align:"center",hidden:true}, 
                {name:'c.code',index:'c.code', width:100}, 
                {name:'p.coeff',index:'p.coeff', width:60,align:"center"}, 
                {name:'a.code',index:'a.code', width:80}, 
                {name:'a.descr',index:'a.descr',width:400},
                {name:'m.code',index:'m.code', width:80}
            ], 
            pager: pager_id, 
            sortname: 'c.code', 
            sortorder: "asc", 
            hiddengrid:true,
            rownumbers: true, 
            rownumWidth: 40, 
            gridview: true,
            scroll:true,
            maxheight: 230,
            autowidth:true,
            onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
                //  montre la colonne sélectionnée pour le tri de la grille
                if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
                                && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).removeClass('ui-state-active');
                }
                $(this.grid.headers[idxcol].el).addClass('ui-state-active');
            },
            altRows:true,
            altclass:'myAltRowClass',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption:'3 - SPECIFICATIONS TECHNIQUES',
            emptyrecords: 'Aucune donnée correspondante...',
        });
        //*********************
        //  4TH SUBGRID 
        //*********************
        rowdata = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',row_id);
        var parc=rowdata['idref'];
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id; 
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_d"; 
        pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id; 
        $("#"+subgrid_id).append("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>"); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({ 
            url:"sg511d.php?id="+row_id+"&parc="+parc, 
            datatype: "json", 
            colNames: ['Id','Ensemble','Quantité','Article','Désignation','Matière'],
            colModel: [ 
                {name:'a.id',index:'a.id', width:60, align:"center",hidden:true}, 
                {name:'c.code',index:'c.code', width:100}, 
                {name:'p.coeff',index:'p.coeff', width:60,align:"center"}, 
                {name:'a.code',index:'a.code', width:80}, 
                {name:'a.descr',index:'a.descr',width:400},
                {name:'m.code',index:'m.code', width:80}
            ], 
            pager: pager_id, 
            sortname: 'c.code', 
            sortorder: "asc", 
            hiddengrid:true,
            rownumbers: true, 
            rownumWidth: 40, 
            gridview: true,
            scroll:true,
            maxheight: 230,
            autowidth:true,
            onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
                //  montre la colonne sélectionnée pour le tri de la grille
                if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
                                && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).removeClass('ui-state-active');
                }
                $(this.grid.headers[idxcol].el).addClass('ui-state-active');
            },
            altRows:true,
            altclass:'myAltRowClass',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption:'4 - PIECES A PREPARER',
            emptyrecords: 'Aucune donnée correspondante...',
            gridComplete:function(){
                colModel = $("#"+subgrid_id+'_d').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                sortName =$("#"+subgrid_id+'_d').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname');
                $('#gbox_' + $.jgrid.jqID($("#"+subgrid_id+'_d')[0].id) +
                        ' tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column').each(function (i) {
                        var cmi = colModel[i], colName = cmi.name;
                        if (cmi.sortable !== false) {
                                $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico').show();
                        } else if (!cmi.sortable && colName !== 'rn' && colName !== 'cb' && colName !== 'subgrid') {
                                $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable').css({cursor: 'default'});
                        }
                        if (cmi.name === sortName) {
                                $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
                                //alert(i);
                                var gridId = $("#"+subgrid_id+'_d').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                                for (var countRow = 0; countRow < gridId .length; countRow ++)
                                {
                                    var rowId = gridId [countRow ];
                                    var dataFromTheRow = $("#"+subgrid_id+'_d').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
                                    $("#"+subgrid_id+'_d').jqGrid('setCell',rowId, i, '','ui-widget-header');
                                    $("#"+subgrid_id+'_d').jqGrid('setCell',rowId, i, '',{'border-top':0,'border-left':0});
                                }
                        }
                });
            },
        }); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{search:false,add:false,edit:false,del:false});
        //*********************
        //  5TH SUBGRID 
        //*********************
        rowdata = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',row_id);
        var btr=rowdata['b.id'],lastId='';
        var prest=rowdata['btype'];
        var nature=rowdata['b.nature'];
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id; 
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_e"; 
        pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id; 
        $("#"+subgrid_id).append("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>"); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({ 
            url:"sg511e.php?id="+row_id+"&btr="+btr, 
            datatype:"json",
            mType:'POST',
            loadui: "disable",
            colNames:['id','Prestations','Radio','Checked','Disabled','Select','Informations'],
            colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id',width:100,hidden:true},
                    {name:'name',index:'name',width:550,sortable:false,
                        formatter: function (cellvalue,options,rowObject) {
                            if(rowObject.radio.length==0){
                                if(rowObject.id.substr(0,1)=='1'){
                                    var check="checked='checked'";
                                }else{
                                    var check='';
                                }
                                if(rowObject.disabled>'0'){
                                    var disabled="disabled";
                                }else{
                                    var disabled='';
                                }
                                var box="<input type='checkbox' class='itmchk' "+check+" "+disabled+"/>";
                            }else{
                                var box="<input type='radio' class='itmrad' id='"+rowObject.radio+"' name='"+rowObject.radio+"' "+(rowObject.checked>0?'checked':'')+" />";
                            }
                            switch(rowObject.level){
                                case '0':
                                    var bstyle="<strong>", estyle="</strong>";
                                    break;
                                case '1':
                                    var bstyle="", estyle="";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    var bstyle="<em>", estyle="</em>";
                            }
                            return box + bstyle + $.jgrid.htmlEncode(cellvalue) + estyle;
                        }
                    },
                    {name:'radio',index:'radio',width:30,sortable:false,hidden:true},
                    {name:'checked',index:'checked',width:30,sortable:false,hidden:true},
                    {name:'disabled',index:'disabled',width:30,sortable:false,hidden:true},
                    {name:'select',index:'select',width:200,sortable:false,hidden:true},
                    {name:'data',index:'data',width:230,sortable:false,
                        formatter: function (cellvalue,options,rowObject) {
                            var cell='';
                            if(rowObject.select>" "){
                                var tab=rowObject.select.split("|");
                                var id=rowObject.id.substr(0,1);
                                cell="<select class='itmsel'>";
                                for(var i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
                                    var fld=tab[i].split(';');
                                    var opt="<option value='"+fld[0]+"' class='myAltRowClass1"+id+"'";
                                    if(i==0){
                                        opt+=" style='font-style:italic;'";
                                    }else{
                                        opt+=" style='color:red;'";
                                    }
                                    opt+=">"+(i>0?'&nbsp;&nbsp;• ':'')+fld[1]+"</option>";
                                    cell+=opt;
                                }
                                cell+='</select>';
                            }
                            return cell;
                        }
                    }
            ],
            sortname: 'id', 
            sortorder: "asc", 
            hiddengrid:true,
            gridview: true,
            treeGrid:true,
            pager:pager_id,
            treeGridModel: "adjacency",
            treedatatype: 'json',
            ExpandColumn: 'name',
            jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
            },
            scroll:true,
            autowidth:true,
            height: 230,
            loadComplete: function() {
                var grid = this;
                resetAltRows.call(this);
                $(this).find('tr.jqgrow td div.treeclick').click(function(){
                        resetAltRows.call(grid);
                });
                $(this).find('tr.jqgrow td span.cell-wrapper').click(function(){
                        resetAltRows.call(grid);
                });
                $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('setLabel', 'name', '<b>'+nature+' - '+prest+'</b>');
                //
            },
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                var $this = $(this),
                isLeafName = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "treeReader").leaf_field,
                localIdName = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "localReader").id,
                localData,
                state,
                setCheckedStateOfChildrenItems = function (children) {
                    $.each(children, function () {
                        $("#" + this[localIdName] + " input.itmchk").prop("checked", state);
                        if (!this[isLeafName]) {
                            setCheckedStateOfChildrenItems($this.jqGrid("getNodeChildren", this));
                        }
                    });
                };
                if (e.target.nodeName === "INPUT" && $(e.target).hasClass("itmchk")) {
                    state = $(e.target).prop("checked");
                    localData = $this.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);
                    setCheckedStateOfChildrenItems($this.jqGrid("getNodeChildren", localData), state);
                }
            },
            onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
                //  montre la colonne sélectionnée pour le tri de la grille
                if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
                                && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).removeClass('ui-state-active');
                }
                $(this.grid.headers[idxcol].el).addClass('ui-state-active');
            },
            caption:'5 - TRAVAUX A EFFECTUER',
        }); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{search:false,add:false,edit:false,del:false});
        //*********************
        //  6TH SUBGRID 
        //*********************
        rowdata = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',row_id);
        var parc=rowdata['p.id'];
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id; 
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_f"; 
        pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id; 
        $("#"+subgrid_id).append("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>"); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({ 
            url:"sg511f.php?id="+row_id+"&parc="+parc, 
            datatype: "json", 
            colNames: ['Id','Ensemble','Quantité','Article','Désignation','Matière'],
            colModel: [ 
                {name:'a.id',index:'a.id', width:60, align:"center",hidden:true}, 
                {name:'c.code',index:'c.code', width:100}, 
                {name:'p.coeff',index:'p.coeff', width:60,align:"center"}, 
                {name:'a.code',index:'a.code', width:80}, 
                {name:'a.descr',index:'a.descr',width:400},
                {name:'m.code',index:'m.code', width:80}
            ], 
            pager: pager_id, 
            sortname: 'c.code', 
            sortorder: "asc", 
            hiddengrid:true,
            rownumbers: true, 
            rownumWidth: 40, 
            gridview: true,
            scroll:true,
            maxheight: 230,
            autowidth:true,
            onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
                //  montre la colonne sélectionnée pour le tri de la grille
                if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
                                && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).removeClass('ui-state-active');
                }
                $(this.grid.headers[idxcol].el).addClass('ui-state-active');
            },
            altRows:true,
            altclass:'myAltRowClass',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption:'6 - INTERVENANTS',
            emptyrecords: 'Aucune donnée correspondante...',
        }); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{search:false,add:false,edit:false,del:false});
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
        //  montre la colonne triée au chargement des données
        colModel = $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
        sortName = $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname');
        $('#gbox_' + $.jgrid.jqID($("#"+subgrid_table_id)[0].id) +
                ' tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column').each(function (i) {
                var cmi = colModel[i], colName = cmi.name;
                if (cmi.sortable !== false) {
                        $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico').show();
                } else if (!cmi.sortable && colName !== 'rn' && colName !== 'cb' && colName !== 'subgrid') {
                        $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable').css({cursor: 'default'});
                }
                if (cmi.name === sortName) {
                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
                }
        });
        //*********************
        //  7TH SUBGRID 
        //*********************
        rowdata = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',row_id);
        var parc=rowdata['p.id'];
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id; 
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_g"; 
        pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id; 
        $("#"+subgrid_id).append("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>"); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({ 
            url:"sg511g.php?id="+row_id+"&parc="+parc, 
            datatype: "json", 
            colNames: ['Id','Ensemble','Quantité','Article','Désignation','Matière'],
            colModel: [ 
                {name:'a.id',index:'a.id', width:60, align:"center",hidden:true}, 
                {name:'c.code',index:'c.code', width:100}, 
                {name:'p.coeff',index:'p.coeff', width:60,align:"center"}, 
                {name:'a.code',index:'a.code', width:80}, 
                {name:'a.descr',index:'a.descr',width:400},
                {name:'m.code',index:'m.code', width:80}
            ], 
            pager: pager_id, 
            sortname: 'c.code', 
            sortorder: "asc", 
            hiddengrid:true,
            rownumbers: true, 
            rownumWidth: 40, 
            gridview: true,
            scroll:true,
            maxheight: 230,
            autowidth:true,
            onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
                //  montre la colonne sélectionnée pour le tri de la grille
                if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
                                && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).removeClass('ui-state-active');
                }
                $(this.grid.headers[idxcol].el).addClass('ui-state-active');
            },
            altRows:true,
            altclass:'myAltRowClass',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption:'7 - PLAN DE PREVENTION',
            emptyrecords: 'Aucune donnée correspondante...',
        }); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{search:false,add:false,edit:false,del:false});
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
        var subgridg="#"+subgrid_id;
        //  #tab_51_1;
        var chaine='abcdefg';
        $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar",subgridg).click(function(){
            var titlebar=this;
            var clicked=chaine.indexOf($(titlebar).parent().attr('id').substr(-1));
            //  id is 'tab51_1_a' so clicked is 0
            var depart=$(titlebar).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
            //  I run my search from id 'tab51_1' class 'tablediv'
            $('#'+depart).find('.ui-jqgrid-view').each(function(idx){
                if(idx==clicked){
                    $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close", titlebar).click();
                }else{
                    if(typeof $(subgridg).find('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv:eq('+idx+')').css('display')=='undefined'||$(subgridg).find('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv:eq('+idx+')').css('display')=='block'){
                        $(subgridg).find(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close:eq("+idx+")").click();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    },
    subGridRowColapsed: function(subgrid_id, row_id) { 
        $("#"+subgrid_id+"_a").remove();
        $("#"+subgrid_id+"_b").remove();
        $("#"+subgrid_id+"_c").remove();
        $("#"+subgrid_id+"_d").remove();
        $("#"+subgrid_id+"_e").remove();
        $("#"+subgrid_id+"_f").remove();
        $("#"+subgrid_id+"_g").remove();
        myGrid.jqGrid('resetSelection');            
    }
});});
```

where I don't use any subGridOptions so I think that false is the defaultValue of reloadOnExpand.
I have added in OnSelectedRow function 2 alerts, at beginning and ending of function.
The first click display fine selrows for begin and end, but for next click, the end alert displays 'null'.

I have tried also to delete all parts into 'subGridRowExpanded' and 'subGridRowColapsed' functions.
The trouble doesn't happen, begin and end selrows are fine and I can edit row as I want.

Inner workings of jqGrid seem very complicate for me as I'm not used to work with it, and I have to thank you one more time for all time you spend for helping noobs as me. You are always right in your comments and I hope you will be for long time on this forum.
Thanks again. Have a nice day. JiheL

**UPDATED 2013-04-22**

After applying all suggests from Oleg, I made some changes in the 20 scripts of my app, which all are built in the same way.
For this subject, here is the small part of onSelectRow I changed :

```
    onSelectRow:function(id){
        var expanded = $("td.sgexpanded", myGrid)[0];
        if(expanded){
            $(expanded).trigger("click").parent().removeClass('ui-state-highlight');                
        }
        myGrid.jqGrid('expandSubGridRow',id);
        $('#'+id).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
        alert(id+' '+myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'));
    },
```

but no more luck for the result, I can't edit a row which has been expanded after collapse other row. I don't understand why selrow changes after collapse old row and expand selected row.
I hope someone could drive me about this trouble, I think I'm not alone to meet this problem.
Many thanks in advance for your kind help, really appreciated. JiheL

**UPDATED 2013-04-23**

After applying Oleg's suggests the main problem (edit an expanded row after collapsing other) seems to be solved. But setting selected row to top of grid runs fine with five first rows, but not with following rows. Strange ! Here is a snapshot of fact :

[image]

Strange because demo in http://jsfiddle.net/jihel/JMcKF/ runs fine and has been created with my app code ! I'm searching what can be wrong or alter scrollTop, if someone has already met such a trouble and have an idea for solving, many thanks for all your help. Have a nice day

Comment: Do you tried to call `myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow')` at the beginning of `onSelectRow` callback? It can be that calls of `collapseSubGridRow` and `expandSubGridRow` could change `selrow` value. Additionally you don't posted more full code which you used. Which value have `subGridOptions.reloadOnExpand` for example?

Comment: @Oleg Many thanks for your reply. I have too many posts simultaneously on this forum and I have forgotten to reply your comments. Sorry. As you can see I have updated my answer with your suggests, but no change. I had a look into the forum about this subject without success, and I don't understand how I could make selrow have the good ID. Many thanks for your kind help, I hope you could have an idea or suggest for that. Have a nice day. JiheL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to analyse so long code. So I post just some comments about the potential problems which I can see in the code after I looked through it.

The main problem which I see: **you should use `idPrefix` option in all subgrids** (or in the main grid and subgrid). The value of `idPrefix` option option should depend on `rowid` where the subgrid will be opened. For example you can use

```
idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_a_"
```

for the first subgrid, `idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_b_"` for the second subgrid and so on.

I recommend you **don't use `.` (dot) or any other [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in the column name**. It's origin of potential errors in your code and in the code of jqGrid. You should understand that the `name` property will be used to build id attributes of some internal elements of jqGrid. There are some restrictions in CSS which characters are permitted in `id` attribute. Additionally jqGrid have to build selectors to get the corresponding elements from the page. For example `$("#" + rowid)` will be wrong selector if `rowid` includes `.` because the selector `("#a.b")` will be interpreted as: element with `id=a` and the class `b` instead of `id="a.b"`. Old versions of jqGrid don't worked at all with such ids and such names. Recent version of jqGrid should works, but nevertheless usage of meta-characters in ids increase the complexity of the code in many time. Do you really need it?

Because of almost the same problem I don't recommend you to use the same `name` property for different tables. It could be important if you plan to use searching filter for multiple grids or subgrids (to use `filterToolbar` for multiple grids). Currently you use `'c.code'` for example in multiple subgrids which is potential origin of the future problems.

If you *really need* to use `.` for searching and you use `datatype: "json"` without `loadonce: true` then you can use `index` which has `.` and `name` which has no `.`. For example you can use `name: 'b_id', index: 'b.id'`. If you use `index` value which is the same as the value of `name` property, it's recommended to *remove* `index` property from the column definition.

Additionally I would don't recommend to use `scroll:true` option of jqGrid. In general virtual scrolling is nice feature, but in my opinion the implementation of virtual scrolling have many bugs abd side effects. So I recommend don't use it. If you really hardly need the feature then you should use it in the form `scroll:1` and you have to invest more time in the debugging.

The last remark: I don't recommend usage of `gridComplete`. I recommend to use `loadComplete` instead. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935) for more details.

The last remark: i recommend to use `gridview: true` in all grids and subgrids which you use.

**UPDATED**: I am not sure that I full understand which behavior you want to implement in `onSelectRow`, but the following implementation

```js
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var $self = $(this),
        $this = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid)), // the row
        $expanded = $self.find("td.sgexpanded");

     if ($expanded.length > 0) {
         $expanded.trigger("click");
     }
     $self.jqGrid("expandSubGridRow", rowid);
     $self.jqGrid("setSelection", rowid, false);
     $this.closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop($this.position().top);
}
```

Comment: Hi Oleg sorry for my late answer. Many thanks again for this BIG answer, I had lot of work for modifying all scripts of my app (20 scripts) I greatly appreciate that not only you corrects that is wrond nut also you teaches and explains why to do as you write. I update my question for following this post. Again many many thanks you're the best ! JiheL

Comment: @JiheL: You are welcome! You could reduce the modifications which you need if you would use jqGrid in a little another way. First of all you should never use variables like `myGrid` inside of callback. You should better use `$(this)`. Next you can define *common parts used in many grids in some separate JavaScript file (`myjqgrid.common.js` for example) which you includes on every page after `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. You can define default implementation of some callbacks (like `onSelectRow`) using `$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {...});`. I do it permanently, so the grids are short and simple.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggest, I am trying to apply it in my app. It's true that makes less work to maintain scripts thanks again for this appropriate suggest. Now I'm looking why I can't edit a row which has been expanded I don't understand it's a brainstorming ! Again thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: I just finish to create a demo about my current problem, in http://jsfiddle.net/jihel/JMcKF/ which shows that the first selected row is editable by edit form, but not following others. Thanks in advance if you could have a look on this demo. Best regards

Comment: @JiheL: Look at "**UPDATED**" part of my answer. It should fix your problem.

Comment: Dear Oleg, you're really a great man ! Perhaps you don't full understand what behavior I want to implement, but you solve the main problem, but something stay wrong. I update my question (the last time I hope) to expose you what is strangely curious. Many many thanks again for your kind help I feel progressing with jqGrid. Have a nice day !

Comment: @JiheL: You are welcome! Sorry, but it's difficult to find the reason of the problem if one have only a demo which have no problem. The only suggestion is that you can try to move the code with `scrollTop` *after* all rows will be expanded or collapsed. If you load the date from the server then if could be some differences to the code of current demo. Moreover I would suggest you to place *new problems* in new question. It will help other people to find the information. Commutative questions can very bad be indexed and found. Have a nice day you too! Best wishes!

Comment: small mistake in your code `$self.jqGrid("setSelection", id, false);` should be `$self.jqGrid("setSelection", rowid, false);`