# jqGrid filtertoolbar not firing after grid resizing

Tags: search, jqgrid, filter, height

I have fixed row numbers to 10 for my subgrids, but if reccount is less than 10 I would want to adjust height subgrid to "auto" or "100%".

So here is my code for this subgrid :

```js
//  SUBGRID FOURTH LEVEL
var subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_d",
    pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id; 
$("#"+subgrid_id).append("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>"); 
$("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({ 
    url:"sg31b.php?id="+row_id+"&clt="+clt, 
    datatype: "json", 
    idPrefix:"sgd_",
    colNames: ['Id','Article','Désignation','Marque','Equivalence'],
    colModel: [ 
        {name:'e.id',index:'e.id',hidden:true}, 
        {name:'a.code',index:'a.code', width:100}, 
        {name:'a.descr',index:'a.descr', width:450}, 
        {name:'k.code',index:'k.code', width:80}, 
        {name:'e.equiv',index:'e.equiv',width:100}
    ], 
    pager: pager_id, 
    sortname: 'a.code', 
    hiddengrid:true,
    scroll:true,
    height:230,
    rowNum:10,
    autowidth:true,
    caption:'4 - EQUIVALENCE ARTICLES',
    gridComplete:function(){
        sortDataCol(this);
        if($("#"+subgrid_id+"_d").jqGrid('getGridParam','records') < $("#"+subgrid_id+"_d").jqGrid('getGridParam','rowNum')){
            $("#"+subgrid_id+"_d").jqGrid('setGridHeight','100%');
        }else{
            $("#"+subgrid_id+"_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',[{npage:1}]).jqGrid('setGridHeight',230);
        }
    }
}); 
$("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{search:false,add:false,edit:false,del:false});
$("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
fullInputCss();
```

and the snapshot of result for less than 10 filtered rows :
[image]

Now if I press Backspace in search field to obtain more rows, it seems that search doesn't fire because Firebug doesn't show any trace of request :
[image]

If I delete added 'setGridHeight' lines in gridcomplete, all runs fine !
I think that one more time I'm wrong in my coding and understanding how jqGrid runs.
Please could someone give me some way to solve this trouble ?
Many thanks in advance. Have a nice day. JiheL

Comment: Try to remove `scroll:true` which you use. Virtual scrolling is nice feature in general, but the implementation in jqGrid contains many bugs and side effects. I don't recommend you to use `.` in the names and recommend you remove `index` property if it has the same value as `name` property. You should better use `$(this)` instead of `$("#"+subgrid_id+"_d")` in every callback. You can remove unneeded `class='scroll'` which you use (twice) and include `row_id` inside of `idPrefix` because one can open more as one subgrids for different rows in the same time. Currently you produce id duplicates.

Comment: I recommend you to add "jquery" or "javascript" as additional tag of all your jqGrid questions to have better colors in the code which you posted. Alternatively you can include `<!-- language: lang-js -->` before the code (don't forget to include one empty line between the code and the comment). See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/147495) for details.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I like the grid colors/styles in the screenshots :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it is PSA theme from jquery-ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the origin of the problem could be **id duplicates** on your page. Just now I wrote [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16077909/315935) on another your question where I described the problem detailed.

Current implementation of jqGrid (version 4.4.5) has problem in the code of `filterToolbar` which constructs `id` for input fields of the filter toolbar based on the following rule:

id="gs_" + cm.name

(see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.custom.js#L418) of code). It means that the id of the input field for the column `a.code` will be `gs_a.code` **for every subgrid which you use**. So you can have id duplicates.

So I recommend you redesign the naming concept in your code. You can use for example

```js
name: row_id + "a_code", index: "a.code"
```

In the way the value like `"a.code"` will be still send during sorting of the grid, but you will have no id duplicates. In some scenarios (is you use `repeatitems: false` in `jsonReader`) you could need to use additional `jsonmap` attribute, but you don't need it in you current code.