# Color of default selected row not changing when selecting another row in jqGrid

Tags: java, javascript, jqgrid

I've a jgGrid in which I'm making the first row default selected on page load.(The selected row is highlighted as yellow). Now when I select some other row in the same jqGrid, the currently selected row and default selected row both are highlighted with yellow color. Ideally when the user selects another row, the previously selected row should not be highlighted yellow.

Below is the snapshot to explain better:

Default Selected row highlighted yellow(in page load):
[image]

Currently selected and Default Selected row BOTH highlighted yellow:
[image]

Below is my jqGrid code:

```
$("#discActionHistGrid").jqGrid({
    url:contextRoot+'discActHist',
    datatype: 'json',
    jsonReader: {repeatitems: false},
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Record ID','Close date','Final Action','Summary','Title','Council','Retraction'],
    colModel: [
               { name: 'referralId', index: 'referralId', width: 25 },
               { name: 'closureDate', index: 'closureDate', width: 30, formatter: function(cellValue){return $.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', new Date(cellValue));}},                   
               { name: 'finalAction', index: 'finalAction', width: 30 },
               { name: 'summary', index: 'summary', width: 50, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;line-height: 1.3em;"'; } },
               { name: 'title', index: 'title', width: 30 },
               { name: 'councilNm', index: 'councilNm', width: 30 },
               { name: 'retract', index: 'retract', width: 30, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {return '<a href="'+ contextRoot +'dart/approved">Retract</a>';} }
    ],loadError: function(xhr,st,err) {
        alert(err);
    },gridComplete: function() {
        $(this).setSelection(1, true);
    },onSelectRow : function(rowid, status, e) {
        var selRow = $(this).getGridParam("selrow");
        var selReferralId = $(this).getCell(selRow, 'referralId'); 
        $("#referralDetailsTab").load(contextRoot+"refDetailsTab?refId=" + selReferralId );
    },
    pager: '#discActionHistPager',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    sortname: 'closureDate',
    gridview: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    hoverrows : true,
    autowidth: true,
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 3,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    altRows:true
});

$("#discActionHistGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#discActionHistPager',
   {
    edit:false,
    add:false,
    del:false,
    search:false,
    refresh:false
});
```

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Edited code after Oleg's advice:

```
$("#discActionHistGrid").jqGrid({
    url:contextRoot+'discActHist',
    datatype: 'json',
    jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "referralId"},
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Record ID','Close date','Final Action','Summary','Title','Council','Retraction'],
    colModel: [
               { name: 'referralId', index: 'referralId', key: true, width: 25 },
               { name: 'closureDate', index: 'closureDate', width: 30, formatter: function(cellValue){return $.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', new Date(cellValue));}},                   
               { name: 'finalAction', index: 'finalAction', width: 30 },
               { name: 'summary', index: 'summary', width: 50, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal;line-height: 1.3em;"'; } },
               { name: 'title', index: 'title', width: 30 },
               { name: 'councilNm', index: 'councilNm', width: 30 },
               { name: 'retract', index: 'retract', width: 30, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {return '<a href="'+ contextRoot +'dart/approved">Retract</a>';} }
    ],loadComplete: function() {
        if (this.rows.length > 1) {
            // select the first row of the grid
            $(this).jqGrid("setSelection", this.rows[1].id, true);
        }
        referralsCnt = $(this).getGridParam("records");
        rowCount = $(this).getGridParam("reccount");            
        if(referralsCnt > rowCount) {
            $("#viewAllReferrals").show();
        }
        $(this).triggerHandler("reloadGrid");   
    },loadError: function(xhr,st,err) {
        alert(err);
    },onSelectRow : function(rowid) {
        $("#referralDetailsTab").load(contextRoot + "refDetailsTab?refId=" + rowid);
    },
    pager: '#discActionHistPager',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    sortname: 'closureDate',
    gridview: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    hoverrows : true,
    autowidth: true,
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 3,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    altRows:true
});
```

Sample JSON Data:

```
{"rows":[{"referralId":"2345","closureDate":1366395788927,"finalAction":"","summary":"","title":"TitleName","councilNm":"CouncilName"},{"referralId":"23455660","closureDate":1366395788927,"finalAction":"Reprimand","summary":"Reprimand and letter of reecommendiation recinded","title":"TitleName","councilNm":"CouncilName"},{"referralId":"23455661","closureDate":1366395788927,"finalAction":"Reprimand","summary":"Reprimand and letter of reecommendiation recinded","title":"TitleName","councilNm":"CouncilName"},{"referralId":"23455662","closureDate":1366395788927,"finalAction":"Reprimand","summary":"Reprimand and letter of reecommendiation recinded","title":"TitleName","councilNm":"CouncilName"},{"referralId":"23455663","closureDate":1366395788927,"finalAction":"Reprimand","summary":"Reprimand and letter of reecommendiation recinded","title":"TitleName","councilNm":"CouncilName"},{"referralId":"23455664","closureDate":1366395788927,"finalAction":"Reprimand","summary":"Reprimand and letter of reecommendiation recinded","title":"TitleName","councilNm":"CouncilName"}],"page":0,"total":0,"records":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a big misunderstanding on what is rowid and that jqGrid *always* need to have unique `id` for every row.

jqGrid is designed to show items from the backend (from the database) in the grid. You have exactly the case. Specially for the case *the most callbacks of jqGrid has rowid as parameter*. If you fill the grid correctly the rowid should have the same value as the `id` from your database table which holds the data.

Only if jqGrid has **wrong input data** which holds no id information then jqGrid has to use some locally generated unique id. Because of the compatibility issues with old versions of jqGrid it still uses the numbers 1, 2, 3 as rowid.

What is a rowid? The grid is constructed based on HTML `<table>`. The body of the table has rows which are `<tr>` in HTML. The implementation of jqGrid must assign some unique values for `id` attribute of the `<tr>` elements (id of rows). One names the `id` values in the documentation as rowids.

What you should do in your case is include `id: "referralId"` inside of `jsonReader` which you use or (better both) include `key: true` property in the definition of `referralId` column:

```
{ name: 'referralId', key: true, width: 25, sorttype: 'integer' }
```

After the changes you can simplify the code of `onSelectRow` callback to

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    $("#referralDetailsTab").load(contextRoot + "refDetailsTab?refId=" + rowid);
}
```

or to

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    $("#referralDetailsTab").load(contextRoot + "refDetailsTab?refId=" +
        encodeURIComponent(rowid));
}
```

to make code cleaner and independent of which value has rowid.

There is no "default selected row" in jqGrid. If you want to select first row on the grid after the grid is loaded you can replace the code of `gridComplete` to the following

```
loadComplete: function () {
    if (this.rows.length > 1) {
        // select the first row of the grid
        $(this).jqGrid("setSelection", this.rows[1].id, true);
    }
}
```

(see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935) where I describe why I recommend use `loadComplete` instead of `gridComplete`)

I hope that after the changes the problem which you described will disappear.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your advice to clean up my code. You're a genius! BUT the initial problem that I had mentioned in my query, still persists. :( The first row selected on the grid load remains highlighted even after I select(and highlight) another row in the grid.

Comment: Also wanted to mention that: Only when I explicitly click the selected(and highlighted) first row and then click some other row, everything works fine, i.e. only the currently selected row is highlighted yellow.

Comment: @tarares: I can't reproduce the problem in my tests. Probably the reason could be in combination with specific data returned from URL `ontextRoot+'discActHist'`. Could you some test JSON data which reproduces the problem?