# Refresh JSON from external PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json, jqgrid, refresh

I want to refresh my data, obtained from an external PHP page, every second. The PHP sends JSON data, retrieved with an AJAX call. With this code, I see the table correctly, but I need to refresh my browser to see the new data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: 'get_data.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems : false,
        },
        colNames: [.............],
        colModel: [.............],
        autowidth: true,
        height: 'auto',
        loadonce: true,
        key: true,
        altRows: true,
        altclass: 'odd',
        rowNum: 100,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        gridComplete: function(){
            if(this.x == undefined){
                var j = 0;
                this.x = 1;
                while(j < mydata2.length){
                    jQuery("#list").addRowData(mydata2[j].id, mydata2[j]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    })
});
```

To update the data I've already tried this:

```
var $grid = $("#list"), timer;
timer = setInterval(function () {
    $grid.trigger('reloadGrid', [{current: true, datatype: 'json', url: 'get_data.php'}]);
}, 1000);
```

And this:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    // ... jqGrid function ...
}, 1000);
```

but neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error is the usage `datatype: 'json', url: 'get_data.php'` as an option of `reloadGrid`. The method `reloadGrid` understand only two options: `current` and `page` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935)). What you need is to reset `datatype` option of jqGrid because of usage `loadonce: true`. So you need replace the line

```
$grid.trigger('reloadGrid',
    [{current: true, datatype: 'json', url: 'get_data.php'}]);
```

called inside of `setInterval` to the following

```
$grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json"})
   .trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
```

It should solve you main problem with refreshing of data. Additionally I would recommend you to examine the code of `gridComplete` which seems me suspected. I don't full understand it. You should take in consideration that `addRowData` calls internal `updatepager` method which calls `gridComplete` and can follows to recursion (see [the line of code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L1855) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935)).

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for reply. i have try your code
`var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $('#list').jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json"}).trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
   }, 1000);`
but in Inspect Element of Chrome I don't see ajax call every second on get_data.php

If I try to write a javascript alert into setInterval it's successful runned every second

Comment: @FrancescoLangiulli: It sounds strange. You can include `beforeRequest` and `loadBeforeSend` callbacks with `alert` and `loadError`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) for some variations of the code of `loadError`. You can additionally to use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and debug the code of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` near the first call of `$.ajax`.