# Get the key value of the row of whose cusstom button has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I found myself in need of what i guess should be a trivial requirement. i have a jqGrid in which i have added a custom button in each row. now i am able to associate a client side click event with it but i want to know the key value (Id) in my case of the row whose custom button was clicked, so that i can proceed with this id and do whatever i want to do.

My code for jqGrid is as below

```
jQuery("#JQGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'http://localhost:55423/JQGrid/JQGridHandler.ashx',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['', 'Id', 'First Name', 'Created Date', 'Member Price', 'Non Member Price', 'Complete', 'customButton'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: '', index: '', width: 20, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false} },
                    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 20, stype: 'text', sortable: true, key: true },
                    { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 120, stype: 'text', sortable: true },
                    { name: 'CreatedDate', index: 'CreatedDate', width: 120, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true} },
                    { name: 'MemberPrice', index: 'MemberPrice', width: 120, editable: true, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'NonMemberPrice', index: 'NonMemberPrice', width: 120, align: "right", editable: true, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'Complete', index: 'Complete', width: 60, align: "right", editable: true, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'customButton', index: 'customButton', width: 60, align: "right" }
                  ],
        rowNum: 10,
        loadonce: true,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#jQGridPager',
        sortname: 'Id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'desc',
        caption: "List Event Details",
        gridComplete: function () {
            jQuery(".jqgrow td input", "#JQGrid").click(function () {
                //alert(options.rowId);
                alert("Capture this event as required");
            });
        }
    });

    jQuery('#JQGrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jQGridPager',
               {
                   edit: true,
                   add: true,
                   del: true,
                   search: true,
                   searchtext: "Search",
                   addtext: "Add",
                   edittext: "Edit",
                   deltext:"Delete"
               },
        {/*EDIT EVENTS AND PROPERTIES GOES HERE*/ },
        {/*ADD EVENTS AND PROPERTIES GOES HERE*/},
            {/*DELETE EVENTS AND PROPERTIES GOES HERE*/},
        {/*SEARCH EVENTS AND PROPERTIES GOES HERE*/}
 );
```

Help or any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main solution of your problem in the following: you need include parameter, for example `e`, in the callback of `click` handle. The parameter has [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) type which contain [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property. Alternatively you can use `this` in the most cases. Having `e.target` you can goes to the closest parent `<tr>` element. It's `id` is the value which you need:

```js
jQuery(this).find(".jqgrow td input").click(function (e) {
    var rowid = $(e.target).closest("tr").attr("id");
    alert(rowid);
});
```

Additionally you should make some other modifications in your code to fix some bugs. The usage of

```js
name: '', index: ''
```

is **wrong** in `colModel`. You should specify any non-empty unique name. For example `name: 'mycheck'`.

Next I recommend you to *remove* all `index` properties from `colModel`. If you use `loadonce: true` you have to use `index` properties with the same values as the corresponding `name` values. If you don't specify any `index` properties you will have smaller and better readable code. The corresponding values of `index` properties will be copied by jqGrid internally from the corresponding `name` values. In the same way you can remove properties like `stype: 'text', sortable: true` which values are *default* values (see `Default` column of [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options&rev=1323692010))

The next problem is that you include probably HTML data in the JSON response from the server. (One can't see any formatter for `customButton` for example). It's not good. In the way you can have problems if the *texts* of the grid contains special HTML symbols. I find better to use *pure data* in JSON response from the server. One can use formatters, [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) etc on the client side. In the case one can use `autoencode: true` option of jqGrid which make HTML encoding of all texts displayed in the grid. In the way you will have more safe code which will don't allow any injection (for example no including of JavaScript code during editing of data).

Next remark: I don't recommend you to use `gridComplete`. The usage of `loadComplete` is better. See [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935) about the subject.

The last important remark. To handle `click` events on the buttons placed inside of grid **one don't need to bind separate `click` handle to every button**. Instead of that one can use *one* `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` callback. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) and [this on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935)e describe this. The answers use `<a>` in custom formatter, but `<input>` works exactly in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write such a comprehensive answer. got it.. infact i am new to jqGrid and have been assigned a task of tweeking with it to have a better understanding of it.. Really its programmers like you who really add value to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that can be used to retrieve the id of the row for which the custom button is clicked is by adding formatter to your custom button cloumn

```
{ name: 'customButton', index: 'customButton', width: 60, align: "right", 
  formatter: function ( cellvalue, options, rowObject ) {

    return "<input type='button' class='custom-button' id='custom"+ rowObject.id +"'/>";
  } 
}
```

Now every button has the row id

```
$('input[id^="custom"]').click(function() {
  var id = this.attr('id').replace("custom", ""); // required row ID
});
```