# first column coming as empty in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

i made one jqgrid . problem is that the first row is coming as empty by default when i am loading that grid.I don't want that empty row...and also i want to set the width of check box column as its heading "Delete" `gridComplete: function() {
                          //alert();
                          jQuery("#udlGrid_cb").css("width","35px");
                          jQuery("#udlGrid tbody tr").children().first("td").css("width","40px");
                          }`[image]

```
jQuery("#udlGrid").jqGrid({
        caption: "Subscriber UDLs",
        height: 500,
        width: 1225,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        datatype: "local",
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        //rowNum: 10,
        rowList:[50, 100, 150, 200],
        gridview: true,
        //loadtext: "Loading...",
       pager: "#pager",
        multiselect: true,
        loadonce: true,
        colNames: colHeaderArray,
        colModel: colModelArray,
        data: colDataArray,
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        sortable: true,
         gridComplete: function() {
                      //alert();
                      jQuery("#udlGrid_cb").css("width","35px");
                      jQuery("#udlGrid tbody tr").children().first("td").css("width","40px");
                      }
    });
    jQuery("#udlGrid").jqGrid("setLabel", "cb", "Delete");
    jQuery('#udlGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: colDataArray}).trigger("reloadGrid",[{current: true}]);...this delete and below checkboxes are coming by default
```

Comment: Could you include `colDataArray` data and `colModelArray`? Why you use `setGridParam` with `{data: colDataArray}` and then trigger `reloadGrid`? You used `data: colDataArray` at the creating of the grid. So the data have already the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the width of multiselect column you should use [multiselectWidth](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) column. It's default value is 20. To have 40px you can use `multiselectWidth: 40` and remove your current `gridComplete`. By the way I don't recommend to use `gridComplete` at all. I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935) for more details.

To help you with first empty row you should include the data which you use to fill the grid and you should include more full code which shows *how you create jqGrid* (with which options).

Comment: thanks for multiSelectWidth.......i am reading one excel sheet and i am populating the grid with excel sheet values....

Comment: @user3381985: You are welcome! Do you have found the reason of the first empty row? Is the problem are solved now?

Comment: no i did not found... i searched but did not get anything which works for me by far...

Comment: @user3381985: Could you append the text of your question with values of `colDataArray` and `colModelArray`? In the case one will be able to reproduce the problem and so to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

share your basic code , which you used to create the jqgrid,
and you can set the width as follows :

```
{ name: 'Criteria', index: 'Criteria', width: 40, align: 'Center'},
```

Comment: in colHeaderArray i am not specifying anything for "Delete".. it is coming by default

Answer (score 0):

Use Css to make the first row of jqgrid invisible

```
   #body .jqgfirstrow{display:none;}//inspect element for the class
```

Set the width during initialization

```
   { name: 'Delete', index: 'Delete', width: 50px, align: 'Center'},
```