# Issue with gridComplete in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a **jQGrid** which has loadComplete and gridComplete parameters. The grid is currently working fine.

Now I had to do a generic change where I need to add one more event which works on the events of the pager.

I added the below code to bind one more event with **gridComplete**.

```
jQuery('#grid0').jqGrid('setGridParam', { gridComplete: function()
            { 
                           myGenericMethod();

            }});
```

**The problem with this code is : myGenericMethod() is called but the original gridComplete block is not executed.**

I am sure @Oleg will be having the answer.

My grid declaration is below:

```
$("#grid0").jqGrid({
         datatype: "jsonstring",


    datastr:GetJSON1(),

    colNames:[strFieldNames[0], strFieldNames[1], strFieldNames[2], strFieldNames[3]],

    colModel:[ 
        {name:'newdynaid', index:'newdynaid', width: 50, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false, size:5}, hidden:true,sortable:false},

        {name:strFieldValues[1], index:strFieldValues[1], editable:false, readonly:true, width:80}, 

        {name:strFieldValues[2], index:strFieldValues[2], editable:false, readonly:true, width:80,
                hidden:false,sortable:true}, 

        {name:strFieldValues[3], index:strFieldValues[3], editable:false, readonly:true, width:80}

        ],


        postData: {},
        rowNum: 10,
        height: "100%",
        shrinkToFit: true,
        autowidth: true,
        rownumbers: false,
        pager: '#pager0',
        sortname: 'id',

        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        emptyrecords: "Empty records",
        loadonce: true,
        sortable: true,

        rowList: [6,10,20,40,60,80,100],

        loadComplete: function() {
             var grid0 = jQuery("#grid0");
             var allDropDownElements = getAllDropDownElements0(); 
            var allDropDownElementRefTables = getAllDropDownElementRefTables0();
             processLoadComplete(grid0, allDropDownElements, allDropDownElementRefTables, 0);
             },
        gridComplete:function() {
             var grid0 = $("#grid0");
             var pager0Center = $("#pager0_center");
             processGridComplete(grid0, pager0Center, 0);
             onLoadpopulateName();
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 4.3.2 jqGrid supports [jQuery Events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2) together with callbacks. At the time I spend many my time to create the corresponding pull request which was merge to the main code of jqGrid. Later in free jqGrid I changed internal code of jqGrid so that practically *every* callback have the corresponding jQuery event. The events are very important if you need to write **common** actions (common callbacks) which need be done on every grid of your project. Only using the events one can write jqGrid **plugin** which don't reserves any callbacks.

The usage of events is very easy. It's important to understand that you can bind the events **before** jqGrid is created. It's especially important to do with events `jqGridBeforeInitGrid` (exist only in free jqGrid), `jqGridInitGrid`, `jqGridGridComplete`, `jqGridAfterGridComplete`, `jqGridLoadComplete`, `jqGridAfterLoadComplete`.

I would recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935) which describes the differences between `gridComplete` and `loadComplete`. I personally use almost only `loadComplete`, but the choice of the callback depend on your exact requirements.

Let us you really need to use *common* `gridComplete`. Then you have choice to define some action *after* `gridComplete` used in the grid or *before* it. Depend on the choice you should use `jqGridGridComplete` or `jqGridAfterGridComplete` event. Let us `jqGridAfterGridComplete` is what you need. Then the code can looks as the following

```
$("#grid0").bind("jqGridAfterGridComplete", function () {
    // the event handler will be executed AFTER gridComplete
    ...
});
$("#grid0").jqGrid({
    // common options which you need
    pager: "#pager0",
    gridComplete:function() {
        var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
            pager0Center = $(p.pager + "_center"); //$("#pager0_center");
        ...
    }
});
```

The above code will work in both jqGrid (starting with version 4.3.2) and free jqGrid. If you would need to use an event which have options, like `jqGridAfterLoadComplete` then you should add *first* additional Event parameter and use the typical parameter starting with the second parameter:

```
$("#grid0").bind("jqGridAfterLoadComplete", function (e, data) {
    // the event handler will be executed AFTER loadComplete
    ...
});
```

By the way free jqGrid allows you to use `pager: true` and don't define an empty `<div id="pager0"></div>`. In the case free jqGrid *generate the div with unique id automatically* and modifies the `pager` option of jqGrid to id selecror. So you can use `gridComplete` callback exactly like in the above example. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/SMALL-improvements-in-the-usage-of-jqGrid) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew you would have an answer to it :)
I am also eager to know, if I want to execute both the gridCompleteFunction on trigger of gridComplete and also the sequence of their execution,  I will be very grateful to you

Comment: @SashiKant: You are welcome! If I correctly understand you then you will need just look at [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L1979-L1981) of code: first `jqGridGridComplete`, then `gridComplete` and finally `jqGridAfterGridComplete`. Free jqGrid do [the same](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/js/grid.base.js#L2978-L2979), but it uses internal `feedback` function which trigger event which name is build based on the name of callback and then calls the callback. In the way one can be sure that both event and callback be called.

Comment: Hey I used `jqGridGridComplete` and this worked. Thanks a lot :)