# jQgrid toolbar searching - dynamically remove search box from any column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, toolbar, jqgrid-asp.net, free-jqgrid

I am using jqgrid version 4.4.4 and right now I am facing one problem related to toolbar searching. As I mention in heading, I want remove search box of toolbar search from any column **"dynamically"** during or after rendering a grid. I google it but I didn't found any relevant solution on my this problem.
      I used `selColProp` property like this

```
$('#<gridId>').jqGrid('setColProp', 'LotNo', {
    search: false
});
```

and mentioned in `loadcomplete` function due to some logical reason.
     If anyone knows how to do this, kindly share your valuable ideas.

**UPDATED:**  Now I am using free jqgrid version 4.9.2 and this functionality also not happening on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching toolbar will be created *once*. It includes all searchable columns in the searching toolbar. If you need to change the `search` property *dynamically* then you have to recreate the searching toolbar after changing the value of `search` property. You need just call `destroyFilterToolbar` to remove the searching toolbar and then call `filterToolbar` once more time.

Alternatively you can consider just to hide the searching field after setting the `search` property to `false`. The corresponding code could be something like

```
$("#gs_LotNo").closest(".ui-search-table").hide();
```

The string `gs_LotNo` is the id of the input field of the `LotNo` column. and using `$("#gs_LotNo").closest(".ui-search-table")` you get the outer table which contains optional searching menu and `x` button. You can consider to make the content of the field empty (`$("#gs_LotNo").val("")`) before hiding to be sure that the current value in the input field will not be used in filters.

Comment: I removed my code of `setColProp` and used your code but nothing happen. I have pasted this code into my `loadComplete` function.

Comment: You should **not remove** setting `search: false`. If you need change the value of `search: false` then you should do this **and** change the searching toolbar *after* that (by recreating the toolbar or by hiding the field). You write about the usage of `setColProp` in `loadComplete`. Why? I can't follow you in the case. What you need to do and how frequently? The `loadComplete` will be called after applying the filter, after sorting and paging an so on. What is your scenario? How you fill the grid? **When** you change `search` property of `LotNo`? Which `datatype` and `loadonce` you use?

Comment: instead of calling this code into `loadComplete`, I called your code in `gridComplete` and wallaaaa.. It worked.  Thank you sir.

Comment: @Rahul: You are welcome! The calling such code in `gridComplete` seems me wrong too. I recommend you to post more full code which should what you do. It's important to know *how you fill the grid with data*, which `datatype` and `loadonce` you use, when later you decide to change the properties. If you load the information from the server and use `datatype: "json"` than you can change column property in `beforeProcessing` callback for example.

Comment: Yes.. you are absolutely right, my `datatype: json` and I didn't used property `loadonce`.

Comment: @Rahul: I recommend you to read [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935) about the difference of `loadComplete` and `gridComplete` and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) as examples of changing `colModel` based on server response inside of `beforeProcessing`