# free-jqgrid, after cancel row edit by escape key press, when I again edit by just selecting that row, it no longer remain set selected

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, free-jqgrid

I am using free jqgrid v4.9.2 in my asp.net project. Here in my jqgrid, I have implemented a functionality is, on select row, selected row became editable. Everything is working fine except by one condition. When first time I select row it get editable and selected too. **But when I cancel row editing by pressing 'ESC' key and again select "THAT" row to edit, it get converted into editable mode but it does not get selected.**

so when I press delete button, row not get delete, because its not selected but I had selected that row.

To get more understanding, here is my jqgrid code:

```
function RenderIGPLotDetailsGrid() {

var oGrid = $('#tbIGPLD'), topPagerSelector = '#' + $.jgrid.jqID(oGrid[0].id) + "_toppager", lastSel;

oGrid.jqGrid({
    url: sRelativePath + '/Ajax.asmx/GetDataForGrid',
    mtype: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
    serializeGridData: function (data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    },
    jsonReader: {
        root: "d.rows",
        page: "d.page",
        total: "d.total",
        records: "d.records"
    },
    colNames: ['UOMId', 'Lot #', 'Wt/Pkg.(Kgs)', 'No. of pkgs.', 'Pkg. type', 'Total Weight'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'UOMId', index: 'UOMId', hidden: true },
        { name: 'LotNo', index: 'LotNo', editable: ($('#hftbIsManualLotNo').val() === '1'), editrules: { required: ($('#hftbIsManualLotNo').val() === '1') }, width: 50 },
        { name: 'GrossWeight', index: 'GrossWeight', template: editNumTemplate, width: 16, editoptions: { maxlength: 18} },
        { name: 'Qty', index: 'Qty', template: editNumTemplate, width: 15, editoptions: { maxlength: 18 },
            editoptions: {
                dataInit: function (domElem) {
                    $(domElem).on("blur", function () {
                        var iQty = $.trim($(this).val());
                        var selrow = oGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                        var value = $('#' + selrow + '_GrossWeight').val() * iQty;
                        $('#' + selrow + '_TotalGrossWeight').val(value);
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        {name: 'UOM', index: 'UOM', template: colTemplate, width: 25, editable: true, edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
        editrules: {
            required: true,
            custom: true,
            custom_func: function (value) {
                if (value === g_sValueNONE)
                    return [false, "Selected UOM is invalid UOM. Please select a valid UOM before saving."];
                else
                    return [true, ""];
            }
        },
        editoptions:
            {
                value: eval('(' + g_oUOMList + ')'),
                dataEvents: [
                    { type: 'keyup', fn: function (e) { $(e.target).trigger('change'); } },
                    {
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            if (!e.isTrigger) {
                                var selrow = oGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                var uomId = $(this).val();
                                oGrid.jqGrid('setCell', selrow, 'UOMId', uomId);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        { name: 'TotalGrossWeight', index: 'TotalGrossWeight', template: editNumTemplate, width: 15, editoptions: { maxlength: 18 },  
            //Place this code in the col options of the last column in your grid
            // it listens for the tab button being pressed
            editoptions: {
                dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).focus(function () { this.select(); }) },
                dataEvents: [
                    {
                        type: 'keydown',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
                            if (key == 9)//tab
                            {
                                var iSalRow = oGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                //Save editing for current row.
                                oGrid.jqGrid('saveRow', iSalRow, { aftersavefunc: function (rowid) { SaveIGPLotDetails(oGrid, rowid); } });
                                //Made flag true to add new row after save opration grid reload
                                g_bIsTabClick = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    prmNames: { page: "pageIndex", rows: "pageSize", sort: "sortIndex", order: "sortDirection", search: "_search" },
    autowidth: true,
    search: false,
    postData: {
        filters: null,
        spName: 'GetIGPLotDetailsList',
        paramXML: $xmlDoc.html().toString()
    },
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20, 50, 100, 150, 200],
    sortname: '',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    page: 1,
    gridview: true,
    toppager: true,
    autoencode: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Lot Details',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    footerrow: true,
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        updateJqGridButtonState($(this), jqGridMode.None)
        // During first time save, by default adding one editable row    
        if (data.d.rows.length <= 0) {
            oGrid.jqGrid('addRowData', 'jqg1', g_oColDefValues, 'first');
            oGrid.jqGrid('editRow', 'jqg1', { keys: true, aftersavefunc: function (rowid) { SaveIGPLotDetails($("#tbIGPLD"), rowid); } });
            oGrid.jqGrid("setSelection", 'jqg1', true);
        }

        //To create new rowm after pressing tab on last column of grid.
        if (g_bIsTabClick) {
            AddNewRow(oGrid);
            g_bIsTabClick = false;
        }
    },
    gridComplete: function () {
        $("table#tbIGPLD tr:last").addClass('ireg-jqgrid-lastrow');
        $("tr.footrow td").addClass('ireg-jqgrid-lastrow').addClass('ireg-jqgrid-footer');
        recalculateWidthInPercent('container', 'tbIGPLD', 0.98);
        var decTotalGrossWeight = $(this).jqGrid('getCol', 'TotalGrossWeight', false, 'sum');
        var decQty = $(this).jqGrid('getCol', 'Qty', false, 'sum');
        $(this).jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { TotalGrossWeight: decTotalGrossWeight, Qty: decQty });
        parent.g_decItemGrossWeight = decTotalGrossWeight;
    },
    //**Here it is a code which converts row into editable mode**
    onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
        // oSavedRows array is not empty if some row is in inline editing mode.
        var oSavedRows = oGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
        if (oSavedRows.length > 0) {
            // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
            // jqGrid hold intern savedRow array inside of jqGrid object,
            // so it is safe to call restoreRow method with any id parameter
            // if jqGrid not in editing state.
            oGrid.jqGrid("restoreRow", oSavedRows[0].id);
        }

        oGrid.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, { keys: true,
            aftersavefunc: function (rowid) {
                SaveIGPLotDetails($("#tbIGPLD"), rowid);
            },
            afterrestorefunc: function (rowid) {
                var iRow = getRowIndex(rowid);
                if (!isValidGuid(rowid) && iRow !== 1)
                    oGrid.delRowData(rowid);
            }
        });
    }
}).jqGrid('navGrid', topPagerSelector, { add: false, edit: false, del: true, search: false, refresh: false
    Removed addParams & editParams because now rows will get editable based on click and will save on enter.
}, {}, {}, myDelParams, {}).jqGrid('inlineNav', topPagerSelector, {});

//iReg-2004: Removed all buttons expect delete
$("#" + $('#tbIGPLD')[0].id + "_top_iledit").remove();
$("#" + $('#tbIGPLD')[0].id + "_top_ilsave").remove();
$("#" + $('#tbIGPLD')[0].id + "_top_iladd").remove();
$("#" + $('#tbIGPLD')[0].id + "_top_ilcancel").remove();                        // #tbItems_top_ilcancel
$("#" + $('#tbIGPLD')[0].id + "_top_ildelete").remove();
$('.ui-separator').remove();                                                    // Separator after the delete button.
```

}

I google a lot to find out solution for this but i didn't find any relevant solution. I appreciate, if anyone address me resolve my this problem. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce the problem. If I click "edit" or "delete" button of `formatter: "actions"` then the row will be always selected before processing of editing or deleting. Could you provide the demo which can I use? In any way you can try to use `singleSelectClickMode: "selectonly"` option (or any other value of `singleSelectClickMode` with exception default value `"toggle"`) which make select behavior the same as in old version of jqGrid: the selected row can't be deselected.

Comment: Actually I am not using button for editing. I am editing when user selects row.

Comment: **Could you provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem?** You code contains many suspected parts. The most suspected is the usage of fix `'jqg1'` rowid in `loadComplete`. You can easy have id duplicates.  I would recommend you to generate unique us using `var newId = $.jgrid.randId();` and then use the id in `addRowData`. In general the usage of `addRow`. You can use `initdata` parameter of `addRow` to specify defaults. Moreover I would strictly recommend you to use `inlineEditing` parameter to specify inline editing options used in **all** calls.

Comment: The current code which you use uses **different** options of `editRow` for the call inside of `loadComplete` and in `onSelectRow`. One uses `afterrestorefunc` another not uses. So 'ESC' key in the first line works not in the same way like in other rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code contains many suspected parts. The most suspected is the usage of fix `'jqg1'` rowid in `loadComplete`. You can easy have id duplicates. I would recommend you to generate unique us using var `newId = $.jgrid.randId();` and then use the id in `addRowData`. In general the usage of `addRow`. You can use `initdata` parameter of `addRow` to specify defaults.

Moreover I would strictly recommend you to use `inlineEditing` parameter to specify inline editing options used in all calls. The current code which you use uses **different options** of `editRow` for the call inside of `loadComplete` and in `onSelectRow`. One uses `afterrestorefunc` another not uses. So <kbd>ESC</kbd> key in the first line works not in the same way like in other rows.

One more problem in your code: you use `selrow` in many places of your code. **Why?** You could use `$(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")` for example inside of `blur` `change` to get rowid **of the current row**. You can use `oGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow")[0].id` in other situations. Your current code **require** that the editing row will be selected. If you don't change the code then the usage of `singleSelectClickMode: "selectonly"` option is really required.

If nothing above helps then you should provide **the demo** and step by step instruction which can be used to reproduce the problem in the demo.

Comment: Great.. the `option` `singleSelectClickMode: "selectonly"` you suggested worked for me. Thank you sir, keep supporting like this.

Comment: Just a humble suggestion sir, why don'y you create documentation of free-jqgrid. As previous version jqgrid documentation/solution is get easily available on net or trirand.com. Now what problem I faced and what solution you gave, that was not present in existing documentation,.If that was present in documentation, then it was very easy to us to find out the solution. Isn't sir?

Comment: @Rahul: The problem is very easy: the time and the money. I provides free jqGrid for free and I receive very few donations. I spend very much my time for preparing last versions of free jqGrid. I have to earn the money for me and my family from other projects. I develop free jqGrid in the rest time. Nevertheless I started new documentation at me internally and I plan to publish it soon. I need just find the time for it.

Comment: I appreciate what are you doing sir.. I am eagerly waiting for free-jqgrid documentation.

Comment: Oleg sir, if you get time. kindly have look on my this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290321/jqgrid-toolbar-searching-dynamically-remove-search-box-from-any-column) question too.