# Speed Up JQGrid Highlighting Row On GridComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I am setting row color based on certain conditions. I have several grids that have several rows. This code is severley slowing down the loading of the page

```
    function setRowColorSetgrid() {
        var rows = $("#Setgrid").getDataIDs();
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var status = $("#Setgrid").getCell(rows[i], "value");
            if (status == "False") {
                $("#Setgrid").jqGrid('setRowData', rows[i], false, {
                    color: 'white',
                    weightfont: 'bold',
                    background: 'red'
                });
            }
        }
    }

 //Have a function to set color for each grid I am loading
    function setRowColorSomeOthergrid() {
        var rows = $("#SomeOthergrid").getDataIDs();
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var status = $("#SomeOthergrid").getCell(rows[i], "value");
            if (status == "False") {
                $("#Somethergrid").jqGrid('setRowData', rows[i], false, {
                    color: 'white',
                    weightfont: 'bold',
                    background: 'red'
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

In the grid Complete of a JQGrid I am calling this

```
    gridComplete: function(){setRowColorSetgrid();}
   //Have a grid creation funcrtion for all the grids I am loading
       gridComplete: function(){setRowColorSomeOthergrid();}
```

This is making the page really big and I think because I am searching each row of each grid for a status "False" its taking forever to load

How can I cut my javascript code down to not having a setRowColor... function for each grid

What other logic can I use to set the row color based on a field value that will perform much better?

Here is my jqgrid. The class never gets applied but the function indeed works to iterate through rows

```
  function INIFiltersgrid() {
            var data = [
                ['INI Exception', 'False', 'INI Path: Not Found'],
            ];
            $("#INIFiltersgrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                height: 500,
                width: 900,
                colNames: ['Name', 'Passed', 'Value'],
                colModel: [{
                    name: 'name',
                    index: 'name',
                    width: 90
                }, {
                    name: 'value',
                    index: 'value',
                    width: 60
                }, {
                    name: 'passed',
                    index: 'passed',
                    width: 240,
                    height: 400
                }],
                gridview: true,
                rowattr: function (rd) {
    if (rd.value === "False") { // verify that the testing is correct in your case
        return {"class": "myAltRowClass"};
    }
                caption: "INIFilters"
            });
            var names = ["name", "value", "passed"];
            var mydata = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                mydata[i] = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                    mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
                $("#INIFiltersgrid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
            }
            $("#INIFiltersgrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
                    alert('double clicked');
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `rowattr` callback function, which allows to add class or to set some attributes (like `style="..."`) on some rows. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) for the corresponding code example. It's important to use `gridview: true` option additionally (see [the answer]). If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), then `gridview: true` option is already default.

By the way I don't recommend you to use `gridComplete`. The callback `loadComplete` is better in the most cases. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935) for more detailed explanation.

**UPDATED**: One should never ever use `addRowData` in the loop to fill the grid. It's the worst way, which I know for filling the grid (and the slowest too). If you need to fill the grid with `mydata` then you should just add `data: mydata` option to the grid. Moreover if you use free jqGrid fork of jqGrid, which I recommended in my answer, then `rowattr` will be still applied even if you use `addRowData`. If you use an old jqGrid then the row added by `addRowData`, will be added **without** applied `rowattr`.

Comment: rowattr hits the function but no matter what I do it does not apply styles

Comment: @nlstack01: You should post the code which you used. What you tried? It could be important to know, which jqGrid version and from which fork you use.

Comment: I added my jqgrid implementation

Comment: @nlstack01: The most important is which CSS rule with `myAltRowClass` you defined. Do you examined CSS of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridChangeRowBackgroundBasedOnCheckboxes3.htm) from the answer, which I referenced? Moreover you still not wrote which version of jqGrid you use.

Comment: @nlstack01: One thing is clear wrong in your code: you should never ever use `addRowData` in the loop to fill the grid. It's the worst way which I know to fill the grid (and the slowest too). If you need to fill the grid with `mydata` then you should just add `data: mydata` to the grid. If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid, which I recommended in my answer then `rowattr` will be still applied. If you use an old jqGrid then the row added by `addRowData`, will be added without applied `rowattr`.