# Jqgrid retrieves all data but have strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In jqgrid I use this part of code to get all data from my jqgrid table:

```
var allRowsInGrid = $('#table_outgoing_calls_report').jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
```

When I console.log allRowsInGrid it shows all data and shows actual length of table data count. But then I try to use this array (allRowsInGrid) it show only data that I see on the screen. Furthermore, if I try to console.log allRowsInGrid.length it shows length of data that I see. 
I use json datatype and loadonce: true. Tried everything but nothing works.
This piece of code:

```
 var allRowsInGrid = $('#table_outgoing_calls_report').jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
        console.log(allRowsInGrid);
        console.log(allRowsInGrid.length);
```

shows this:
[image]

Does anyone know how it can be possible?

Comment: The problem is not *what you do*, but *when* and *where* you use `'getGridParam','data'`. You can use `data` **after** the data are loaded first from the server. You can use there for example inside of `loadComplete` or inside of `beforeProcessing` callback. Please write additionally *in all questions about jqGrid* **the version** of jqGrid, which you use and **the fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: @Oleg, you are totally right. I just used getGridParam in gridComplete function. Thanks a lot. You can answer the question and I mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not *what you do*, but *when* and *where* you use 'getGridParam','data'. You can use data **after** the data are loaded first from the server. You can use there for example inside of `loadComplete` or inside of `beforeProcessing` callback. I'd recommend you to read [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935) additionally, which describes the differences between `loadComplete` and `gridComplete`. In the most cases `gridComplete` isn't the good choice.

Moreover, `loadComplete` will be called *not only after the first loading* from the server. It will be called later on every local sorting, paging and filtering/searching. If one needs to make some actions once after loading the data from the server then `beforeProcessing` callback is good. It contains *full data* returned from the server *before* the data will be processed by jqGrid. One can for example modify or extend the data inside of `beforeProcessing` callback and jqGrid will see the modified data as if it was returned so from the server.

One more option - to place some code in `loadComplete` inside of `if ($(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") !== "local") { ... }`. It allows to do some action *after* the data loaded from the server have processed and the first page was displayed.